# hbase-indexer+Phoenix: hbase replication not working?

Tags: solr, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a cluster with HBASE+Phoenix.
I've installed SOLR on it.
Now I'm trying to set up hbase replication for the cluster, following this manual:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/1181/hbase-indexing-to-solr-with-hdp-search-in-hdp-23.html

Started hbase-indexer server, added hbase-indexer, put data via hbase shell, requested commit via browser. 
But there are no changes in the collection in SOLR - zero new records.

*Status 'replication'* command in hbase shell increases sizeOfLogQueue with each PUT command to the indexed table.

When greping hbase log (hbase-hbase-regionserver-myserver.log) I found lots of records like this:

> Indexer_hbaseindexer: Total replicated edits: 0, currently replicating
>   from:
>   hdfs://HDP-Test/apps/hbase/data/WALs/myserver,16020,1519204674681/myserver%2C16020%2C1519204674681.default.1519204995372
>   at position: 45671433

The position here never changes.

[Issue author on this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-3846) tells that when changing WAL codec to IndexedWALEditCodec, the hbase replication stops.

Is it real that IndexedWALEditCodec stops hbase replication from working correctly? That shouldn't be true.
What may be a problem then? Any hint would be appreciated

env:

- HDFS           2.7.3
- HBASE          1.1.2
- SOLR           5.5.2
- HBASE  INDEXER 2.2.8

p.s. When restarting Hbase, then querying solr commit, the changes appear. But afterwards it doesn't do anything.